# How to Encalsulate Page Structure / Routes in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, url-routing, encapsulation

I have a regular angular 4 app and I use Router, ActivatedRoute.params.subscribe, [routerLink] etc. to navigate between pages and interpret URLs.

Now this leads to the fact, that I have a lot of "magic strings" flying around because many different .ts-Files have url-fragments in them. Of course it works, because they match, but it seems kind of entangled to me. Here is a random example:

`<a [routerLink]="['/foo']">Home</a>
 <a [routerLink]="['/foo/item', 1]">Item 1</a>
 <a [routerLink]="['/foo/item', 2]">Item 2</a>`

One idea I had is to build a service that does the url-building for the components and therefore knows about the url structure. This is just one Idea that I had but I am not that experienced with angular and maybe "magic strings" are the way to go for some reason.

Is there a best practice to keep url structure out of your components?

Comment: I would configure them in the component

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi, that would at least get the urls out of the html template. Thx for the idea!

Comment: you're welcome, then you can implement the service that holds the full routes map and can figure out the possible routes based on the current component route, kind of it takes the current route `service.get(currentRoute)` and returns the list of possible routes and you can then use them in the template

Answer (score 2):

This is why I've been using the router dependency from my components and navigate manually to each of my destinations everytime. Sure if the routes changes I'll have to change some few strings but I'm okay with that.

For that purpose I also created a navigation component that would display me the routes of my application. I even tried to dynamically build my application routes with a lot of meta-data and rights management but I eventually destroyed my lazy-loading possibility, so I'd not advice to do that.

To me, the best thing yet, is to build a navigation component that will consume a single Router configuration (well it depends on your needs).
Here is what I'm talking about : https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin/blob/master/src/app/pages/pages.menu.ts

and the demo app : https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin

Comment: yeah, that's also interesting idea